# Torah or Sorah?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash

What is the difference between Torah with a taf and Sorah with a saf?

For example, in Tehillim 119, the word תורתיך or תורת is written about 20 times, half of the times it is written with a taf, and the others are with a saf. Is there a difference in meaning? Why is one chosen over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is either in the beginning of a verse, or after a “separating” cantillation, or if the previous word ends with a consonant, then it is a “Tav”

Comment: Thank you. So there is no difference in meaning? It is simply a grammatical rule?

Comment: That’s correct!